How to remove all plots using httpgd in vscode?
I am using VSCODE with R. Is it possible to delete all plots at once? I mean delete, not hide

Use:
dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])


It does not work
Error in if (which == 1) stop("cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

There is still one for placeholder, which is the default. Try while (dev.cur() > 1) dev.off()
